# I have to validate a text box in .NET MVC where the text box value is less than or equal the difference of two column values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, html.textboxfor

A Text box field has to be validated such that the value must be less than or equal to the calculated value (Difference between two column values).
For example, I have two Columns TodaysDateTime and TomorrowsDateTime the difference between these two is calculated in mins this mins value is the maximum value for the text box.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text) <= (TomorrowsDateTime - TodaysDateTime))
{
    // show alert or error dialogue
}
```

Comment: Can we handle this from model??

Comment: `if (int.Parse(mins) <= (model.TomorrowsDateTime - model.TodaysDateTime)) { // do something }`. Ensure that the `model` is a viewmodel class (note that you need to include controller code example).

Comment: From Controller, It would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can validate at model level by using Custom Validation

(Assuming you are ready to prepare your model accordingly i.e. **ViewModel**).

**Your Model:**

```
 [testValidator]
    public partial class Cal
    {
        public DateTime todayDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime tommorwDateTime { get; set; }
        public int result {get; set;}
    }
```

**CustomValidator:**

```
   class testValidator : AbstractValidator<test>
   {
    public override ValidationResult Validate(test obj)
    {

    if(Convert.ToInt32(obj.result ) <= (todayDateTime  - tommorwDateTime ))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;  
        }
    else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Please Enter a Valid Dates.");  
        }

    }

}
```

At Your controller. you can simply check `Model.IsValid`

Hope this helps.